# Project Reactor: Designing a reactive API

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have a map function which defined as follows: `Mono<OUT> map(IN in)`

Here's a concrete example:

```
public Mono<Integer> map(String s) {
            return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1_000); // simulate HTTP request
                    return 1;
                } catch (Exception e) {}

                return -1; // need to return something.
            });
        }
```

The problem is that in case of an error (i.e. `IOException`), we still need to return some output. There's also a possibility that there might no be an answer (but no error occurred)

One solution could be an `Optional::empty` but I think it's cumbersome. Preferably, I'd like to return `Mono::empty` if an error occurred.

The reason is, `Mono::empty` gets consumed by the subscriber without any further handling. Here's an example:

```
Flux.just(
                Mono.just("123"),
                Mono.empty(),
                Mono.just("456")
        ).flatMap(s -> s)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

The output would be:

> 123
>   456

How can achieve the same behaviour?

What should `map` look like?

**EDIT:**
Rethinking it, maybe I better off return some container (like `Optional`) or a custom one (`Result`) which can be empty.

Comment: Why not return Mono.empty() inside the catch block?

Comment: @uneq95, notice the try-catch is inside the `Mono.fromCallable`

Comment: But you have not returned anything from the catch block. The return statement in your code snippet is outside the catch block.

Comment: yeah, it could be inside the catch (doesn't really matter). The thing is, you must return something from the Callable, whereas I'd like to return a `Mono::empty` to the caller of `map`, in case there's no answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, here's what you need:

```
return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {  
    Thread.sleep(1_000); // simulate HTTP request
    return 1;
}).onErrorResume(_ -> Mono.empty())
```

Comment: @yaseco you can also return null inside of the callable lambda (e.g.: in case of no answer), that will result in an empty Mono: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-